# Perl: Difference in code

Tags: perl, operators

I am new to Perl and I am trying to find the difference between two snippets:

```
$string && $string eq 'foo'
$string eq 'foo'
```

I tried several conditions but I am not able to find the difference. Can somebody help me identify the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One difference is that the 2nd line could generate a warning message (when using `use warnings;`) if the variable has never been assigned a value:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string;

if ($string && $string eq 'foo') {
    print "true1\n";
}
else {
    print "false1\n";
}

if ($string eq 'foo') { # Get warning
    print "true2\n";
}
else {
    print "false2\n";
}
```

The warning message is:

```
Use of uninitialized value $string in string eq
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not considering `use strict` and `use warnings`

Comment: Always consider using `strict` and `warnings`. And by consider, I mean commit to. :-)